# Informix PDO at ubuntu 12.10

Tags: php, ubuntu, pdo, informix

I'm configuring the PDO at ubuntu.

And i'm getting this error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/pdo_informix.so' - libifcli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

Any clues?, the driver is set correctly and also de envvars.

Comment: The library that's missing is one of the Informix CSDK libraries (for the ODBC interface).  That's normally found in $INFORMIXDIR/lib/cli directory; you might find that $INFORMIXDIR/lib and perhaps $INFORMIXDIR/lib/esql need to be searched too.  You could add these to `/etc/ld.so.conf`, or you can try setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  I'm not sure whether the bug report related to `php5-suhosin` is directly relevant; if it is, then maybe none of this matters.  If it is not relevant, then you should look hard at this issue.

Comment: I agree with Jonathan, this what is missing here is the LD_LIBRARY_PATH defined when the apache was started. At opensuse I define this variables into the /etc/sysconfig/apache2...

Answer (score 2):

Finally just changed the directory from /opt/IBM/informix to just /opt/informix.

That did the trick for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is a known bug and has been reported [here #666911](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=666911)(terrific number there) `=)`.

Just purge `php5-suhosin` package.

Comment: A beastly emergency for a bug report number!